# How can I print a huge number in Lua without using scientific notation?

Tags: lua, scientific-notation

I'm dealing with timestamps in Lua showing the number of microseconds since the Epoch (e.g. "1247687475123456").

I would *really* like to be able to print that number in all its terrible glory, but Lua insists on printing it in scientific notation. I've scoured the available documentation about printing a formatted string, but the only available commands are "Print in scientific notation (%e/%E)" and "Automatically print in scientific notation if the number is very long (%g)". No options seem to be available to print the number in its normal form.

I realize that I could write a function that will take the original number, do some dividing by 10 and print the digits in a loop but that seems like an inelegant hassle. Surely there's some way of doing this that's built in to the language?

Comment: Related for other languages: [Haskell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8098457/how-do-i-get-to-haskell-to-output-numbers-not-in-scientific-notation) [Lua](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1133639/how-can-i-print-a-huge-number-in-lua-without-using-scientific-notation) [C++ ostreams](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2335657/prevent-scientific-notation-in-ostream-when-using-with-double) [Delphi](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6077153/how-to-disable-scientific-notation-in-asstring-in-delphi)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
> print(string.format("%18.0f",1247687475123456))
```

1247687475123456

Comment: You can omit the width; "%.0f" will use exactly as many digits as needed.

Comment: /facepalm!

Man, I tried all manner of format strings but never considered the floating-point option. Thanks!

Comment: @NathanKitchen - `"%.f"` is the same as `"%.0f"` but a bit shorter

Answer (score 9):

Lua as usually configured uses your platform's usual double-precision floating point format to store all numbers. For *most* desktop platforms today, that will be the 64-bit IEEE-754 format. The [conventional wisdom](http://lua-users.org/wiki/FloatingPoint) is that integers in the range -1E15 to +1E15 can be safely assumed to be represented exactly.

In any case, the [`string.format()`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-string.format) function passes its arguments through (with some minor tweaks) to the platform's implementation of [`printf()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/printf/). The format string understood by `printf()` includes `%e` and `%E` to force "scientific" notation, and `%f` to force plain decimal notation. In addition, `%g` and `%G` choose the shortest notation.

For example:

```
E:\...>lua
Lua 5.1.4  Copyright (C) 1994-2008 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
> a = 1e17/3
> print(string.format("%f",a))
33333333333333332.000000
> print(string.format("%e",a))
3.333333e+016
> print(string.format("%.0f",a))
33333333333333332
```

Note that if the value fits within a 32-bit signed integer range, you can also use the `%d` format. However, results are not well defined if the value exceeds that range. System timestamps in microseconds are likely to exceed the 32-bit range.

If 16 decimal digits is not enough precision, there are several choices available for increased precision.

First, it would not be difficult to package a true 64-bit integer in a `userdata` along with a suitable set of arithmetic metamethods. This gets discussed occasionally on the [Lua mailing list](http://www.lua.org/lua-l.html), but I don't recall seeing a completed module released by anyone.

Second, one of the Lua authors has released two modules supporting arbitrary precision arithmetic: [lbc and lmapm](http://www.tecgraf.puc-rio.br/~lhf/ftp/lua/). Both are found at that page.

Third, casual searching in Google readily turns up several other math library wrappers.