# Prevent scientific notation in ostream when using << with double

Tags: c++, iostream, scientific-notation

I need to prevent my double to print in scientific notation in my file,

when I do this

```
outfile << X;
```

Comment: Related for other languages: [Haskell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8098457/how-do-i-get-to-haskell-to-output-numbers-not-in-scientific-notation) [Lua](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1133639/how-can-i-print-a-huge-number-in-lua-without-using-scientific-notation) [C++ ostreams](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2335657/prevent-scientific-notation-in-ostream-when-using-with-double) [Delphi](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6077153/how-to-disable-scientific-notation-in-asstring-in-delphi)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

To set formatting of floating variables you can use a combination of [`setprecision(n)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setprecision), [`showpoint`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/showpoint) and [`fixed`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/fixed). In order to use parameterized stream manipulators like `setprecision(n)` you will have to include the iomanip library:

```
#include <iomanip>
```

`setprecision(n)`: will constrain the floating-output to `n` places, and once you set it, it is set until you explicitly unset it for the remainder of the stream output.

`fixed`: will enforce that all floating-point numbers are output the same way. So if your precision is set to 4 places, `6.2`, and `6.20` will both be output as:

```
6.2000
6.2000
```

`showpoint`: will force the decimal portions of a floating-point variable to be displayed, even if it is not explicitly set. For instance, `4` will be output as:

```
4.0
```

Using them all together:

```
outfile << fixed << showpoint;
outfile << setprecision(4);
outfile << x;
```

Comment: What makes you think that showpoint makes any difference here? The decimal portion is always shown with 0's due to the precision.

Comment: All I needed was to include `<iomanip>` and use `setprecision(n)`

Answer (score 10):

Here's an example of usage 
http://cplus.about.com/od/learning1/ss/clessontwo_4.htm

as per your question use

```
  std::cout << std::fixed << a << std::endl;
```

Comment: Better answer since it directly answers the question ('fixed').

Answer (score 6):

All the above answers were useful, but none directly answer the question.

```
outfile.setf(std::ios_base::fixed);
outfile << x;
```

I found the answer in @moogs link: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/fmtflags

Here's a demo program: http://ideone.com/FMxRp1

Comment: Can't edit right now, but that gives a 404. Try http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/fmtflags (thanks Moogs)

Answer (score 2):

you can use format flags

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/fmtflags