# How to convert a floating point value in exponential form to dot notation?

Tags: c++, oracle, floating-point

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Prevent scientific notation in ostream when using << with double](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2335657/prevent-scientific-notation-in-ostream-when-using-with-double)

I get 1e-1 as result after a computation how can I convert the result from exponent to dot notation i.e., 0.1 ? Why is it automatically  converted to exponential notation!!

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `fixed` I/O manipulator to force the number to be printed in fixed-point notation:

```
double d = 42.0;
std::cout << std::fixed << d;
```

(`std::scientific` does the opposite:  it forces the number to be printed in scientific notation)

Comment: I would like to save the value in double!

Comment: @yesraaj:  What do you mean?  42.0 is 42.0 and how you format it for printing has no effect on the stored value.

Comment: I save the value into a database, where I use double being converted to appropriate NUMBER type in Oracle.

Comment: @yesraaj: Then it's oracle that has the problem, not C++

Answer (score 0):

Oracle (generally) doesn't do binary numbers ([some support was added in 10g](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements001.htm#i140176)).
Numbers are held in an internal format and, unless you use an implicit or explicit TO_CHAR, it is up to the "client" to display them (or any desired "prettifying").

```
select to_number('1e-1') num, 
       to_char(to_number('1e-1'),'9.9EEEE') sci_num, 
       to_char(to_number('1e-1')) std_num 
from dual;

            NUM SCI_NUM   ST
--------------- --------- --
            .10   1.0E-01 .1
```