# How to make C++ cout not use scientific notation

Tags: c++, double, cout, ostream, scientific-notation

```
double x = 1500;
for(int k = 0; k<10 ; k++){
    double t = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<12; i++){
        t += x * 0.0675;
        x += x * 0.0675;
    }
    cout<<"Bas ana: "<<x<<"\tSon faiz: "<<t<<"\tSon ana: "<<x+t<<endl;      
}
```

this the output

> Bas ana: 3284.78        Son faiz: 1784.78       Son ana: 5069.55
>
> Bas ana: 7193.17        Son faiz: 3908.4        Son ana: 11101.6
>
> Bas ana: 15752  Son faiz: 8558.8        Son ana: 24310.8
>
> Bas ana: 34494.5        Son faiz: 18742.5       Son ana: 53237
>
> Bas ana: 75537.8        Son faiz: 41043.3       Son ana: 116581
>
> Bas ana: 165417 Son faiz: 89878.7       Son ana: 255295
>
> Bas ana: 362238 Son faiz: 196821        Son ana: 559059
>
> Bas ana: 793246 Son faiz: 431009        Son ana: 1.22426e+006
>
> Bas ana: 1.73709e+006   Son faiz: 943845        Son ana: 2.68094e+006
>
> Bas ana: 3.80397e+006   Son faiz: 2.06688e+006  Son ana: 5.87085e+006

I want numbers to be shown with exact numbers not scientific numbers. How can I do this?

Comment: Why are you casting a `double` to `double`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Prevent scientific notation in ostream when using << with double](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2335657/prevent-scientific-notation-in-ostream-when-using-with-double)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prevent scientific notation in ostream when using << with double](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2335657/prevent-scientific-notation-in-ostream-when-using-with-double)

Answer (score 139, accepted):

Use [`std::fixed`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/fixed) stream manipulator:

```
cout<<fixed<<"Bas ana: "<<x<<"\tSon faiz: "<<t<<"\tSon ana: "<<x+t<<endl;
```

Answer (score 42):

As mentioned above, you can use `std::fixed` to solve your problem, like this:

```
cout << fixed;
cout << "Bas ana: " << x << "\tSon faiz: " << t << "\tSon ana: " << x+t <<endl;
```

However, after you've done this, every time you print a `float` or a `double` *anywhere in your project*, the number will still be printed in this fixed notation. You could turn it back by using

```
cout << scientific;
```

but this might become tedious if your code gets more complicated.

This is why Boost made the **I/O Stream State Saver**, which automatically returns the I/O stream you're using to the state it was before your function call. You can use it like this:

```
#include <boost/io/ios_state.hpp> // you need to download these headers first

{
    boost::io::ios_flags_saver  ifs( os );

    cout << ios::fixed;
    cout<<"Bas ana: "<<x<<"\tSon faiz: "<<t<<"\tSon ana: "<<x+t<<endl;

} // at this bracket, when ifs goes "out of scope", your stream is reset
```

You can find more info about Boost's I/O Stream State Saver in [the official docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/libs/io/doc/ios_state.html).

You may also want to check out the [Boost Format library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/libs/format/doc/format.html) which can also make your outputting easier, especially if you have to deal with internationalisation. However, it won't help you for this particular problem.

Answer (score 18):

code the next syntax:

```
std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(n);
```

where `(n)` is the number of decimal precision.
This should fix it.

P.s.: you need to `#include <iomanip>` in order to use [`std::setprecision`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setprecision).

Answer (score 11):

In C++20 you'll be able to use [`std::format`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format) to do this:

```
std::cout << std::format("Bas ana: {:f}\tSon faiz: {:f}\t"
                         "Son ana: {:f}\n", x, t, x + t);
```

Output:

```
Bas ana: 3284.776791    Son faiz: 1784.776791   Son ana: 5069.553581
Bas ana: 7193.172376    Son faiz: 3908.395585   Son ana: 11101.567961
...
```

The advantage of this approach is that it doesn't change the stream state.

In the meantime you can use [the {fmt} library](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt), `std::format` is based on. {fmt} also provides the `print` function that makes this even easier and more efficient ([godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/8bf1Kn)):

```
fmt::print("Bas ana: {:f}\tSon faiz: {:f}\tSon ana: {:f}\n", x, t, x + t);
```

**Disclaimer**: I'm the author of {fmt} and C++20 `std::format`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use format flags

More info: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ios_base/fmtflags/

Answer (score 2):

You can use the function **fixed** in this way :

> std::cout << std::fixed << ...

Or you can use the the printf function with a standard format like "12.12%f" in this way :

> printf ("number = %12.12f", float_number);

Answer (score 1):

There are a whole collection of formatting operators that you get with iostream.  Here's a [tutorial](http://www.arachnoid.com/cpptutor/student3.html) to get you started.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `printf` in c++ to print in the value without scientific notation.

As You can also use`cin` and `cout` instead of `scanf` and `printf`, however, if you are taking a million numbers as input and printing a million lines, it is faster to use `scanf` and `printf`.

```html
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

  int main () { 
  double a = pow(2,99); 
  printf ("%lf\n",a); 
  return 0; 
  }
```

Output

```html
633825300114114700748351602688.000000
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
double x = 1500;
  for(int k = 0; k<10 ; k++){
    double t = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<12; i++){
        t += x * 0.0675;
        x += x * 0.0675;
    }
    cout<<"Bas ana: "<< fixed << x <<"\tSon faiz: "<<t<<"\tSon ana: "<<x+t<<endl;      
}
```

- You can use `<< fixed <<` to show exact numbers and not scientific numbers.
- It is a small, easy fix ;)

***If you want the ouput to be in 2 decimal places, you can use this code: ***

(Use `#include <iomanip>` and then type `<< setprecison(n) << "  after  " << fixed <<` , where '`n`' is the number of decimal places you want. So, in your case, you can use 2 for `n` and get 2 decimal places. The full code is written below.)

```
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  double x = 1500;
  for(int k = 0; k<10 ; k++){
    double t = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<12; i++){
        t += x * 0.0675;
        x += x * 0.0675;
    }
    cout<<"Bas ana: " << fixed << setprecision(2) << x <<"\tSon faiz: "<<t<<"\tSon ana: "<<x+t<< endl;      
}
}
```