# Print double without scientific format & rounded to nearest integer

Tags: c++, double, rounding, scientific-notation

I need to print rounded off integers without using exponential denotations/parts.
I'm currently using this to print rounded decimal.

```
std::cout << std::llround(n) << n;
```

However, it still prints like this for big numbers

```
1264744611.26474e+08
```

Suggestions, please?
And my question is different from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5212018/making-c-cout-not-use-scientific-notation) as it does not take care of rounding off. On trying fixed with llround, I get numbers trailing with .000000

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Making C++ cout not use scientific notation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5212018/making-c-cout-not-use-scientific-notation)

Comment: No, as it does not take care of rounding off.
I just tried llround & fixed together. But got numbers trailing with .000000

Comment: What exactly is the value of `n`, how do you want to print it and how does the current output differ?

Comment: `std::llround` returns `long long`. It should not get formatted as floating point. Post the smallest program you can write that compiles, links, and shows the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at what you're sending to std::cout...

```
std::cout << std::llround(n) << n;
```

...two values **without** any intervening punctuation or whitespace.  Put a newline or something between them and I think you'll find the code is doing precisely what it should.  e.g.

```
std::cout << std::llround(n) << "\n" << n;
```