# Print whole non-decimal part of a double

Tags: c++, printing, output, double, cout

Let's say I have a `double d = 123456789` (I know that the double is always representing an integer). I am trying to print it using C++ so that exactly `123456789` is printed. Unfortunately, this is not the default behavior:

```
double d = 123456789;
cout << d << "\n";

output: 1.23457e+08
```

I discovered the following trick/cheat:

```
double d = 123456789;
cout << (long) d << "\n";

output: 123456789
```

Is this the way to do it, or is there a cleaner way using some output manipulators?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make C++ cout not use scientific notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5212018/how-to-make-c-cout-not-use-scientific-notation)

Comment: TL;DR potential dupe: `std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(0) << d;`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[std::setprecision](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setprecision) can be used here.

```cpp
#include <iomanip>   // std::setprecision
#include <iostream>  // std::cout

int main() {
  double d = 123456789;
  std::cout << std::setprecision(5) << d << "\n";
  // 1.2346e+08
  std::cout << std::setprecision(15) << d << "\n";
  // 123456789
}
```

The maximum precision can be set with

```cpp
std::setprecision(std::numeric_limits<long double>::digits10 + 1)
```

Comment: When `d > 1e15` or so, output still uses `e+`.  `double` typically has a range up to `1e308`.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: I'll leave this here for the info about casting, but the right way is to use [setprecision](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setprecision) as suggested in the other answers.

Casting to `long` is fine as long as your values can fit in a `long`. You can upgrade to `long long` or `unsigned long long` if you are dealing with values larger than can be represented by `long`. (use the signed version to support negative values).

Keep in mind that `double`/`float` can represent very large values so eventually you might encounter values that don't fit even in `unsigned long long`.

You can check for overflow with something like

```
if (d <= (double)std::numeric_limits<long long>::max()
     && d >= (double)std::numeric_limits<long long>::min())
{
    cout << (unsigned long long) d;
}
else
{
    cout << "value d is very large: " << d;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use manipulator and set the output format as shown below

```
double d = 123456789;
std::cout << std::setprecision(9) << std::noshowpoint;
std::cout << d << std::endl;
```