# why this code is producing is output in terms of exponential for large values

Tags: c++, cout

Why the code(A) is producing is output in terms of **exponential** for large values.

for eg:-`input(in)=1400000 output:-1.2375e+006(without using variable k)`.

An integer "in" denoting income in rupees is given. Find net income. The net income is calculated by subtracting the total tax (also called tax reduction) from the total income.

```
long long int in;
        cin>>in;
        long long int a,b,c,d,e;
        a=(250000)*0.05;
        b=(250000)*0.10+a;
        c=(250000)*0.15+b;
        d=(250000)*0.20+c;
        e=(250000)*0.25+d;
```

## code without using variable (long long)k

## code(A)

```
        cout<<1LL*in<<endl;
        else if(in<=500000)
        cout<<1LL*(in-((in-250000)*0.05))<<endl;
        else if(in<=750000)
        cout<<1LL*(in-a-((in-500000)*0.10))<<endl;
        else if(in<=1000000)
        cout<<1LL*(in-b-((in-750000)*0.15))<<endl;
        else if(in<=1250000)
        cout<<1LL*(in-c-((in-1000000)*0.20))<<endl;
        else if(in<=1500000)
        cout<<1LL*(in-d-((in-1250000)*0.25))<<endl;
        else
        cout<<1LL*(in-e-((in-1500000)*0.30))<<endl;
```

**whereas 
`input(in)=1400000 output:-1237500(using variable (long long)k)`**

## code using (long long)k

## code(B)

```
        long long int k;
        if(in<=250000)
          k=in;
        else if(in<=500000)
          k=(in-((in-250000)*0.05));   
        else if(in<=750000)
          k=(in-a-((in-500000)*0.10));
        else if(in<=1000000)
          k=(in-b-((in-750000)*0.15));
        else if(in<=1250000)
          k=(in-c-((in-1000000)*0.20));
        else if(in<=1500000)
          k=(in-d-((in-1250000)*0.25));
        else 
          k=(in-e-((in-1500000)*0.30));
        cout<<k<<endl;
```

Comment: That’s the default format. You can change it to something else you want if you don’t want it that way

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make C++ cout not use scientific notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5212018/how-to-make-c-cout-not-use-scientific-notation)