# how to avoid "exponent" format when printing double to stringstream

Tags: c++

I print double to stringstream this way::

```
std::stringstream message;
message << sss[j]->stocks << '/' << std::setprecision(5) << sss[j]->profit << '/' << sss[j]->lastPrice;
std::cout << std::setw(30) << message.str();
```

`sss[j]->profit` is double. I want it to be printed "without E", but in output I still have something like this:

```
-560000/4.076e+005/0.7394
```

How to avoid `e`?

Comment: Change the [format](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/fixed).

Comment: By reading the [relevant pages of the manual](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/fixed)

Comment: Exact duplicate of [How to keep doubles from converting to scientific notation when using and stringStream](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6010838/how-to-keep-doubles-from-converting-to-scientific-notation-when-using-and-string)

Answer (score 1):

Use [std::fixed](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/fixed)

```
std::cout << std::fixed << sss[j]->stocks << std::endl;
```

And btw the "*e*" comes from the so called *scientific*-notation.