# setprecision + fixed - printing value without unnecessary zeros

Tags: c++

The following code:

```
double x = 3.14;
double y = 3.14159265359;
cout<<fixed<<setprecision(6)<<x<<", "<<y<<endl;
```

prints: 3.140000, 3.141593

I want to print values without unnecessary zeros:
3.14, 3.141593 How to do that without using the string and stringstream classes ?

Comment: `fixed` makes the stream to show trailing zeros. Don't use it.

Comment: Fixed is necessary because I want to set precision for the fractional part of the number. Without fixed I get 3.14159

Comment: iostreams doesn't have manipulators that are sophisticated enough to do this, it really is up to you to whack those zeros from the string.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Prevent scientific notation in ostream when using << with double](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2335657/prevent-scientific-notation-in-ostream-when-using-with-double)

Answer (score 2):

When neither fixed nor scientific format is chosen, the meaning of `setprecision` is the number of **all** digits to output (not just after the dot).

Therefore, this should work for you

```
double x = 3.14;
double y = 3.14159265359;
cout<<setprecision(7)<<x<<", "<<y<<endl;
```

Output:

```
3.14, 3.141593
```

Answer (score 2):

You may use `cmath` to count the digit of integer parts as shown:

but if number small than 0.1 will be wrong

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    double a = -123.456789;
    double b = 4567.45;
    if (a > 1 || a < -1){
        cout << setprecision(5 + int(log10(fabs(a)) + 1)) << a << endl; //anser is -123.45679
    }
    else {
        cout << setprecision(5) << a << endl;    // if a = 0.0123456 answer will be 0.012347
    }
    if (b > 1 || b < -1){
        cout << setprecision(5 + int(log10(fabs(b)) + 1)) << b << endl; //anser is 4567.45
    }
    else {
        cout << setprecision(5) << b << endl;
    }
}
```