# How do I make "std::cout << 123456789.12" print "123456789.12"?

Tags: c++, decimal, cout

How do I make

```
std::cout << 123456789.12
```

print this:

```
123456789.12
```

It always prints this:

```
1.23457e+008
```

I know that I have to play with the flags, but I cant quite figure out the right combination. If I set the fixed flag, it prints

```
123456789.120000
```

Comment: std::setprecision : http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setprecision

Comment: ??? NEW CPP programmer why did u add the STL Flag ??
Anyways u can set the precision by `std::setprecision(int )`
try `std::cout << std::setprecission(20) << 123456789.12 << endl;`

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22177656/convert-double-to-string-with-fixed-point-notation-no-trailing-zeroes-and-witou

Comment: What do you want to see in general? Fixed notation and 2 digits after the point? 11 digits in total?

Comment: Heh.  The smart-alec answer would be to put the number in quotes:  `std::cout << "123456789.12";`

Comment: I just want the trailing zeros to vanish. But I want it to show all digits necessary. So, if there are three digits after the point, I want it to show them.

Comment: "if there are three digits after the point, I want it to show them" -- zero is a digit.  Suppressing trailing zeros is usually both difficult and unwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    double c = 123456789.12;
    cout.precision(numeric_limits<double>::digits10 + 1);
    cout << c << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Basically the [`limits` package](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/limits) has traits for all the build-in types.
One of the traits for floating point numbers (`float/double/long double`) is the [`digits10` attribute](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/digits10). This defines the accuracy of a floating point number in base 10.

See it live: http://ideone.com/Ity9m7

---

To read on, check out another similar question: [How do I print a double value with full precision using cout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/554063/how-do-i-print-a-double-value-with-full-precision-using-cout)

Comment: Note, the final digit you get from `+1` isn't to be taken as useful information, except to be able to serialize and restore the value exactly.

Answer (score 11):

*How to ...* ?

One way :-

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main() {
    double f =123456789.12;
    std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(2) << f << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

See [here](http://ideone.com/SbCqWW)

Please look for appropriate references

Answer (score 0):

You can use boost::lexical_cast as follow:

```
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>

std::cout << boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(123456789.12);
```

more info can be found in http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_lexical_cast.html