# Locale-awareness of ostringstream when reading an entire file

Tags: c++, io

I want to read a binary file into a vector of bytes `vector<int8_t>`. The function shouldn't be aware of the file's encoding / language / etc, I just want the raw bytes.

I read through the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116038/what-is-the-best-way-to-read-an-entire-file-into-a-stdstring-in-c) and this [excellent article](http://cpp.indi.frih.net/blog/2014/09/how-to-read-an-entire-file-into-memory-in-cpp/), and since my files are not very large the recommended solution seems to be

```
std::ifstream in("file.txt", std::ios::binary);
auto ss = std::ostringstream{};
ss << in.rdbuf();
auto s = ss.str();
```

and then creating a vector from `s`.

However I don't like the idea of reading my raw bytes through an `ostringstream` which **is** locale-aware, especially that its default locale [depends](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34925854/4154993) on your machine's settings.

Are my concerns legit? Will this solution produce different results on different machines with different global locales? Should I call `ss.imbue(std::locale::classic());` first? How do I guarantee that the `ostringstream` won't mess with the content? Or does opening the file itself in a binary mode guarantee that?

Comment: Why use a `stringstream` for a binary file?  Try using `std::vector` with an `istream` iterator.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews this is listed as "Bad idea #1" in the article I linked due to its terrible performance

Comment: If you are looking for performance, get the size of your file, then dynamically create an array and use `std::istream::read` to read the entire file into the array.  Otherwise search the internet for "memory mapped files" and include your platform name.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews this is listed as "Bad idea #2" in the article I linked due to the UB it may cause:) Yes, I am looking for performance. It's on Windows.

Comment: @Valentin http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_streambuf says that it does use the locale   "Typical implementation of the std::basic_streambuf base class holds only the six CharT* pointers and a copy of std::locale as data members. In addition, implementations may keep cached copies of locale facets, which are invalidated whenever imbue() is called. The concrete buffers such as std::basic_filebuf or std::basic_stringbuf are derived from std::basic_streambuf."