# Why my code is given me wrong results?

Tags: c++

I don't know why my code is giving to me incorrect results.

When I put a number like `6670680902` the result is `6.67068e+0.7` (which is `66706800`). That is not the correct result. 
When I use the calculator the correct result of `667006080902 / 100` is `66706809.02`.

What should I do to fix it?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "conio.h"
#include "iostream"

using namespace System;
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    float a;
    float b;

    cout << "Ingrese el codigo: "; cin >> a;

    b = a / 100;

    cout << "result: " << b;

    _getch(); 
    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: You do realize that `float`s have only seven, or so, significant digits, right?

Comment: Floats are specifically less precise to save memory, they should not be used for highly precision expected answers. Instead use a double or long double. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386772/what-is-the-difference-between-float-and-double

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: i tried with the double and long double type and still wrong result.

Comment: @ErnestoPacheco By default C++ output automatically makes large numbers into scientific notation, it does not mean `6.67068e+0.7` is `66706800`. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2335657/prevent-scientific-notation-in-ostream-when-using-with-double

Comment: C++ is not C, please don't spam tags

Comment: Seems fine to me, using your number and a few others. https://ideone.com/vBlTzG

Comment: @RetiredNinja Your using a `double`, a `float` which OP is using will not have the correct value. OP is also not making `cout` use precision printing, making it show as scientific notation.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek OP stated he used doubles and still had trouble. Asserting that the program doesn't match a calculator seems like an issue with printing the numbers. I chose to avoid that issue.

Comment: @RetiredNinja It's both using a `float` and printing the numbers as scientific notation as I mentioned a few times above. The reason why OP says it gives the same result is because they are printing it as scientific notation, even if the number is actually correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first issue here is by default C++ will show larger numbers using scientific notation, [there are ways to prevent this for floating point numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2335657/prevent-scientific-notation-in-ostream-when-using-with-double) like floats. One simple way is to add `<< fixed` before your number:

```
cout << "result: " << fixed << b;
```

Which will return `66706812.0`.

The next problem is that `floats` are not good at being precise, which is why the number still isn't correct. [Floats are less precise compared to something like a double which has twice the precision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386772/what-is-the-difference-between-float-and-double). If you use a `double` instead for `a` and `b`:

```
int main()
{
    double a;
    double b;
    //...
    cout << "result: " << fixed << b;
    //...
}
```

you will get the value you expect: `66706809.02`

Comment: Thank you it works also! but gives 66706809.020000. but is perfect thank you man!

Answer (score 1):

Can do by using 'limits`

```
#include "iostream"
#include <string>
#include <limits>

using namespace System;
using namespace std;

int main()
{
 double a;
 double b;

 cout << "Ingrese el codigo: "; cin >> a;

 b = a / 100;

  cout.precision(numeric_limits<double>::digits10 + 1);

  cout << "result: " << b << endl;
  _getch(); 
 return 0;
 }
```

Output:

```
result: 66706809.02
```

Comment: It works with this cout.precision(numeric_limits<double>::digits10 + 1); thank you !!