# How to disable scientific notation in .AsString in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, scientific-notation

Hi
I want to get numbers from database, for example, if the number in database is 44.7890000000, I would like to get a string 44.789, the same 0.0010000000 -> 0.001, just keep the numbers and trim the tailing '0'. 
I use this code:
qrySth.Fields[i].AsString - it does its job but I find for very small numbers like 0.0000010000 it becomes 1E-6. Is there a way I could disable the scientific notation for this AsString method?

Thanks!

Comment: I think maybe I need to use displayformat

Comment: You should add that comment as an answer, Spspli.

Comment: Is there a way I use AsString, but can control its display to non-scientific number?

Comment: 'DisplayFormat' does not change what 'AsString' returns, it only effects the GetText method of the field which is used in data aware controls.

Comment: Related for other languages: [Haskell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8098457/how-do-i-get-to-haskell-to-output-numbers-not-in-scientific-notation) [Lua](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1133639/how-can-i-print-a-huge-number-in-lua-without-using-scientific-notation) [C++ ostreams](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2335657/prevent-scientific-notation-in-ostream-when-using-with-double) [Delphi](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6077153/how-to-disable-scientific-notation-in-asstring-in-delphi)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an alternative to setting the field's [`DisplayFormat`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/DB.TNumericField.DisplayFormat) property, you can read from `AsFloat` and pass the value directly to [`FormatFloat`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/SysUtils.FormatFloat). It uses the same format pattern.

Comment: If I use AsFloat, due to the floating number expression nature, it will give me a number not exactly the same as what it is in database. There will be extra rounding problem. So I don't want to use AsFloat

Comment: What type is the database field? (I don't mean the Delphi TField class. I mean the field in the DB schema.)

Comment: @spspli - Both 'AsFloat' and 'AsString' will first retrieve the field's value from the database, both will use the `GetData` method. You have a problem with one, you have it with both.  'AsString' will, *additionally*, convert the value to string using [`FloatToStr`](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/SysUtils_FloatToStr@Extended.html), which uses 'ffGeneral' for [FloatFormat](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/SysUtils_TFloatFormat.html) with 15 significant digits.