# How do I get to haskell to output numbers NOT in scientific notation?

Tags: haskell, formatting, scientific-notation

I have a some items that I want to partition in to a number of buckets, such that each bucket is some fraction larger than the last.

```
items = 500
chunks = 5
increment = 0.20


{- find the proportions  -}
sizes = take chunks (iterate (+increment) 1)    
base = sum sizes / items    
buckets = map (base *) sizes

main = print buckets
```

I'm sure there is a mathematically more elegant way to do this, but that's not my question.
The end step is always printing out in scientific notation.

How do I get plain decimal output? I've looked at the [Numeric](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Numeric.html) package but I'm getting nowhere fast.

Comment: Related for other languages: [Haskell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8098457/how-do-i-get-to-haskell-to-output-numbers-not-in-scientific-notation) [Lua](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1133639/how-can-i-print-a-huge-number-in-lua-without-using-scientific-notation) [C++ ostreams](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2335657/prevent-scientific-notation-in-ostream-when-using-with-double) [Delphi](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6077153/how-to-disable-scientific-notation-in-asstring-in-delphi)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try [printf](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Text-Printf.html#v:printf). e.g.:

```
> import Text.Printf
> printf "%d\n" (23::Int)
23
> printf "%s %s\n" "Hello" "World"
Hello World
> printf "%.2f\n" pi
3.14
```

Answer (score 13):

```
> putStrLn $ Numeric.showFFloat Nothing 1e40 ""
10000000000000000000000000000000000000000.0
```