# stack overflow error while implementing a Recursive Function(factorial)

Tags: function, recursion, lua, factorial

I tried to implement a factorial function like this:

```
function factorial(n)
    if (n == 0) then
        return 1
    else
        return n * factorial(n - 1)
    end
end

io.write("number?")
n =io.read()
fac = factorial(n)
print("factorial of",n,"=",fac)
```

It works fine until I give `0` as input. It returns

```
lua: factorial.lua:5: stack overflow
stack traceback:
                factorial.lua:5: in function 'factorial'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Also, It gives normal output only till `16`. when I give `n=17`, output is         `3.55687428096e+014`

How to get it right?

Comment: `n=17` answer is correct. It's just printed in scientific notation.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp yeah,  what to do to get just the number? in normal representation.

Comment: @Alaye http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1133639/how-can-i-print-a-huge-number-in-lua-without-using-scientific-notation

Comment: Also, to get "0" to work, tell `read` to read a number: `n = io.read("*n")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get "0" to work, tell `read` to read a number: `n = io.read("*n")`

To get the normal notation instead of scientific notation,use

```
print("factorial of",n,"=",string.format("%0f",fac))
```